# Scala3 inline if reuse result of function

Tags: scala, lambda, functional-programming

```scala
val num = 3
val x = if (func(num) > 3) func(num) else 4
```

How can i avoid calling `func(num)` twice here? My project is fully functional so calling `func(num)` twice is guaranteed to yield the same result. Does the compiler optimize this automatically? I am aware of this:

```scala
val num = 3
val x = List(num).map(f(_)).map(a => if (a > 3) a else 4).head
```

EDIT: I'm looking for a way to improve this

```
val temp = tl.indexWhere(<bool>)
val insertIndex = if(temp == -1) tl.size else temp
```

Answer (score 1):

The Scala compiler will generally not know if a function is pure, so it cannot perform that optimization automatically.

```scala
val temp = tl.indexWhere(???)
val insertIndex = if(temp == -1) tl.size else temp
```

Is very likely the clearest and (by explicitly preventing double evaluation) most performant expression of this logic.  Assuming that `temp` is a local variable, the Scala compiler *can* see that it's not used later in your function/method and reuse the local variable slot.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you want to make it abundantly clear that the local variable is only used for this particular block of code, you could utilize … a block of code:

```scala
val insertIndex = { val temp = tl.indexWhere(<bool>); if (temp == -1) tl.size else temp }
```

or

```scala
val insertIndex = {
  val temp = tl.indexWhere(<bool>)
  if (temp == -1) tl.size else temp
}
```

As mentioned in another answer, Scala cannot, generally, know that `tl.indexWhere` is pure, since Purity Analysis is equivalent to solving the Halting Problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is an improvement but you can use pattern matching with guard:

```scala
val num = 3
val x = num match {
  case v if v > 3 => v
  case _ => 4
}
```

Or in second case simply:

```scala
val insertIndex = tl.indexWhere(...) match {
  case -1 => tl.size
  case v => v
}
```